# Он наверно был большая шишка в городе, коли на его похороны сам бургомистр пришел

Tags: синтаксис

*Он наверно был большая шишка в городе, **коли на его похороны сам бургомистр пришел.***

В книгах написано, что "раз", "коли" и "если" вводят придаточные условия. 
Может я неправильно рассуждаю, но у меня так получается:

Основание: тот, кто умер, был важная персонa в городе;

Результат: на его похороны пришел бургомистр.

Это на самом деле какой-то другой тип предложения или я не вижу условия?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это особый подтип условных предложений, которые выражают **реализованное** условие (а не потенциальное или ирреальное условие, как обычно), их еще называют **несобственно-условными**, так как в них гипотетичное значение ослабляется или утрачивается и они сближаются с другими типами сложных предложений.

Предложения с союзом РАЗ/КОЛИ близки по семантике  к причинным предложениям и имеют значение **довода, логического обоснования**, такое же значение имеют **двухместные** союзные средства вида ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ.

Он **навЕрно** был большая шишка в городе, **коли** на его похороны сам бургомистр пришел.  Здесь  мы видим двухместный союз НАВЕРНО...КОЛИ, в придаточной части содержится основание (коли), а в главной ― вывод, умозаключение (с наречием "наверно" в качестве структурного элемента).

Comment: Вы выделили слово "наверно" запятыми. Не знаю как в первоисточнике, но запятые меняют смысл ( без запятых  "наверно" значит "наверняка", с запятыми  - "возможно"). По смыслу больше подходит без запятых.

Comment: Возможно, Вы правы, форма  "наверно"  в значении "наверняка" мне кажется архаичной, но и текст старый. Пример из Нацкорпуса: Император Александр III был русский патриот, но высоко благородный и с точки зрения благородства его души, он, конечно, был Русским Императором, потому что он наверно был благороднее, нежели все его верноподданные. [С. Ю. Витте. Воспоминания (1911)]

Answer (score 1):

Он наверно был большая шишка в городе, коли на его похороны сам бургомистр пришел.
Основание: тот, кто умер, был важная персонa в городе;
Результат: на его похороны пришел бургомистр.
Это на самом деле какой-то другой тип предложения или я не вижу условия?

1) А Вы попробуйте поменять местами простые предложения.
Условие: коли (если) на его похороны сам бургомистр пришел;
Следствие: он наверно был большая шишка в городе
2) Кроме того, я согласна с Sibilla (извините, не знаю, как правильно просклонять по - английски), что данное придаточное близко по семантике к придаточному причины.